# Multiplying column values with ability to add/delete rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, multiplication, worksheet-function

I have an invoice, where there are two columns: `Rate` (Column H) and `Quantity` (Column I). And there is `Amount` (Column J).

I need a formula so that it would automatically multiply `Rate` and `Quantity` and show it in `Amount`. The number of rows would be changing (added or deleted), but the formula should still work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `ArrayFormula()` spans from row 5 ("Books Name") to row 14 ("Total Price"), so adding rows or deleting them should not be a problem:

```
=ArrayFormula(if((C5:C14="Books Name")+(C5:C14="Total Price")=1,"",H5:H14*I5:I14))
```

[image]

However, since the formula will have to reside in the column J, the following formula is even more useful:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C5:C14="Books Name","Amount",if(C5:C14="Total Price","",H5:H14*I5:I14)))
```

Comment: Thanks @ZygD. The solution works perfectly what  I needed. Thanks again. With this solution, my workflow has completely gone Google.

Comment: I wish to have the text "Amount" in the formula.

Comment: This is what I thought about later. Take a look at your document once again.

Comment: Thanks ZygD. I have copied all the options in the original worksheet. I am happy like a child with all the solutions provided by you.:) You make my day.